# Code works on one machine but not the other

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation

a little back story about my situation.

I don't know how to code, and have very little knowledge in the general field. I recently hired someone on upwork to complete an automation tool for me. In a recent demo that we had over Zoom, the tool/code worked on her computer. So she sent me the files and when I ran it on my computer, it completed about half of the automation process and then stopped.

From what I saw, the code is the exact same thing that she is running. She doesn't know what the issue is and I haven't a clue what is wrong but have been trying to trouble shoot myself. Is there anything that I can look into that could be the cause?

This is the error that keeps popping up:

```
ERROR - Reason of failure {}
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.click()" because "newPostBtn" is null
```

Not sure if this is helpful, but the files that run this code are a PROPERTIES file, batch file, and jar file.

I thought it could be a syntax issue with the font or something but after retyping the code it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: "newPostBtn" is null. That  thing doesn't exist, either you need some fallback code to handle that case or check before attempting to click it.

Comment: Are you scrapping some webpage with selenium ? Are you running the script/tool on the exact same page than the developper ? if *newPostBtn* is null, it`s probably because selenium cannot find the requested id/attribut on the dom to retrieve this button. SO either the DOM is not the same as your developper ( not same webpage/url, settings...) or... i don`t know. Maybe you could explain a bit more the context and share some code if possible

Comment: @AlexNoonan To summarize, 1) The error _NullPointerException_ is a common issue and known to all java professionals. 2) _"newPostBtn" is null_ type of issue is a common issue for the Selenium users. There are different approaches to solve the error but each size won't fit all. Solution may vary usecase to usecase.